# Oracle SQL View with select statement in where

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

Hello I have a problem with one of my views.

I use this statement a view times

```
where date=(select d from user_date_table)
```

This works fine for the result but the perfomance is very slow.

When I do the following:

```
where date=to_date(
```

This is a lot faster but this will not work here since I have to give the view this value.

Is there anything else I can do?

Right now I've tested it with a package that has a function package_name.get_user_date that gives me the value. But this is also very slow.

Are there any other things that would maybe could make this query faster?

Thank you!

Comment: "This is a lot faster but this will not work here since I have to give the view this value. " ... I don't understand, what you mean here.. Have you done an explain plan of your query? You could transform your subselect to a join.

Comment: Show us the complete query, the definition of the tables involved and the execution plan for both queries. [**Formatted**](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Is there only one date in column `d` in `user_date_table`? Hard to believe. And if there is more than one date, the query will not work. So, if it does work, you aren't showing us your real query. Why not? Anyway: in the subquery, `(select TO_DATE(d, '......') from ....where....)`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible ways you could try and resolve this.
Does user_date_table have duplicate dates in it?

If not, then you could join to this table in the query instead of putting it into a where clause.

If it does, then you could change the query in the view to
select ...
from yourTable t
where exists 
(
  select * 
  from user_date_table udt 
  where udt.d = r.date
)

Also, check and see what indexes are on the user_date_table. Maybe there is a function based index on to_date(d) which is why this works faster.